# Whenever I attempt to enter the information for a bronze statement it outputs the silver statement. How do I fix this issue?

Tags: c++11, if-statement

> So every time I enter in 0 and a number less than 1000 it is supposed to output the bronze 
>        statement.
>   Instead it always outputs silver and I can't figure out the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    float moneySpent;
    int yearsAttended;
    enum class Level { bronze, silver, gold, platinum };
    Level memberLevel{};

    cout << "How many years have you attended the club. " << endl;
    cin >> yearsAttended;
    cout << "How much money have you spent in the club" << endl;
    cin >> moneySpent;
    {
        if ((yearsAttended == 0) && (moneySpent >= 1000)) {
            memberLevel = Level::bronze;
            cout << "Welcome to the club, you are bronze rank. " << endl;
        }
        else if ((yearsAttended <= 1) && (moneySpent <= 1000)) {
            memberLevel = Level::silver;
            cout << "Congratulations on reaching silver. " << endl;
        }
        else if ((yearsAttended <= 5) && (moneySpent <= 10000)) {
            memberLevel = Level::gold;
            cout << "Congratulations on reaching gold level. Thank you for all you have done. " << 
endl;
        }
        else if ((yearsAttended <= 7) && (moneySpent <= 15000)) {
            memberLevel = Level::platinum;
            cout << "You have reached platinum level. We apprectiate all you have done to help. " << 
endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `if ((yearsAttended == 0) && (moneySpent <= 1000))` ?

Comment: Yes, this is where I'm running into the problem.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. Your first cindition should be like the one in my comment above - Because of "enter in 0 and a number less than 1000 it is supposed to output the bronze"

Comment: Well I feel stupid now, that solved the problem and it's working perfectly now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)